# PHP Multidimensional array into an HTML nested list?

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, html-lists

I have an array with data that is nested as per the below (just a simplified example as it has to be "endless" since each family tree can go over X generations):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 121
    [name] => Very Important Dogs Bowey Showey
    [gen] => 0
    [mother] => Array
        (
            [id] => 128
            [name] => Veridique Of Winners
            [gen] => 1
            [mother] => 
            [father] => 
        )

    [father] => Array
        (
            [id] => 124
            [name] => Rosickys Robocopico
            [gen] => 1
            [mother] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 75
                    [name] => Astro Spice
                    [gen] => 2
                    [mother] => 
                    [father] => 
                )

            [father] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 62
                    [name] => Your King of the World
                    [gen] => 2
                    [mother] => 
                    [father] => 
                )

        )

)
```

And I tried with this PHP function but without success because it indeed goes through each array and creates a bullet point, but I cannot isolate "name" and "ID" as they all come together.

```
function recurseTree($var){
  $out = '<li>';
  foreach($var as $v){
    if(is_array($v)){
      $out .= '<ul>'.recurseTree($v).'</ul>';
    }else{
      $out .= $v;
    }
  }
  return $out.'</li>';
}

echo '<ul>'.recurseTree($familytree).'</ul>';
```

And this is what it gives me:

```
- 121Very Important Dogs' Bowey Showey0
    - 128Veridique Of Winners1
    - 124Rosicky's Robocopico1
        - 75Astra's Spice2
        - 62Lazhar's King of the World2
```

It gives me an unusable string. Instead, I want to use something like `$v['id']` to get the id (and create an a `href` link) and the name with something like `$v['name']`... But how?!

The format I am after:

```
  <ul>
    <li><span>Mother</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span><a href="#">Grandmother</a></span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Grand-Grandmother</span></li>
            <li><span>Grand-Grandfather</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span><a href="#">Grandfather</a></span>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Father</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span><a href="#">Grandmother</a></span>
        <li><span><a href="#">Grandfather</a></span>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do:

```
function recurseTree($var)
{
    $out = '<li>';
    foreach($var as $k => $v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            $out .= '<ul>'.recurseTree($v).'</ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            switch($k)
            {
                case 'id':
                    $out .= 'id='.$v;
                break;

                case 'name':
                    $out .= 'name='.$v;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $out.'</li>';
}

echo '<ul>'.recurseTree($familytree).'</ul>';
```

Comment: would use a `switch`, more readable than a series of `elseif` (made an edit)

Comment: @GuillaumeDupre

thank you guillaume and bobot, it almost does what i want with the only exception that i cannot create links because ID and NAME cannot be merged together such as <a href="link.php?id=$v">$v</a>

Comment: @Bob0t it almost does what I need, just the formatting is not the one I am after
    <ul>
      <li><span>Mother</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li><span><a href="#">Grandma</a></span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>Grand-Grandma</span></li>
              <li><span>Grand-Grandpa</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span><a href="#">Grandma</a></span>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Father</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li><span><a href="#">Grandma</a></span>
          <li><span><a href="#">Grandpa</a></span>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Because your array is associative and appears to follow a consistent format, I think you can actually do this without using a loop at all. This should make the formatting much easier.

```
function recurseTree($var) {
   if ($var) {
     $link = '<span><a href="link.php?id='. $var['id']. '">'. $var['name']. '</a></span>';
     $parents = '';
     if ($var['mother'] || $var['father']) {
        $parents = '<ul>'. recurseTree($var['mother']). recurseTree($var['father']). '</ul>';
     }
     return "<li>$link$parents</li>";
   }
}
echo '<ul>' . recurseTree($familytree) . '</ul>';
```